# JavaFX Application Bundle Version Number

Tags: linux, macos, javafx, deb, dmg

I’m creating an installable bundle for a JavaFX 8 application using the Oracle tool that comes with the JDK.  On a Mac a `.dmg` file is created and on Linux a `.deb` file is used.  I call an Ant script from Gradle to create the bundle.  The problem that I have is that the version number contained in the bundle is always 1.0 and not the version that I specify.  The relevant part of the Ant script is as follows:

```xml
<project name="VocabHunter Packaging" basedir=""
         xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

    <target name="jfxbundle" description="Build the application bundle">
        <fx:deploy outdir="${basedir}/build"
                   nativeBundles="${packageType}">

            <fx:application refId="VocabHunterId"
                            version="${version}"/>

            <fx:bundleArgument arg="mac.CFBundleVersion"
                               value="${version}"/>
            ...
        </fx:deploy>
        ...
    </target>
    ...
</project>
```

You can see the full script in context [here](https://github.com/VocabHunter/VocabHunter/blob/1.0.8/package/bundle-ant.xml).

On a Mac, right-clicking the application icon and selecting “Get Info” shows 1.0 instead of the correct version number as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: Mac Screenshot]

Similarly, on Linux the version number shows as 1.0 during the installation of the `.deb` file:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix Ant script so that the correct version appears?

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_66 on both the Mac and on LInux.

Comment: Where do you define the version variable?

Comment: @hotzst The version number is defined in the Gradle script that calls the above Ant script.  To remove any doubt, I just did a test on the Mac and hardcoded the version number into the Ant script and I still observe the same problem in the generated bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved this.  The problem it would seem, was caused by the fact that I had a `<fx:application>` element with a `refid` attribute referring to a separate `<fx:application>`.  The solution was to combine these two `<fx:application>` elements into a single element, as follows:

```xml
<fx:application id="VocabHunterId"
                name="VocabHunter"
                mainClass="${mainClass}"
                version="${version}"/>
```

I found that I had to include the `id="VocabHunterId"` attribute for some reason: without it the file association did not work.

I've tested this out and it works nicely showing the version number correctly for the installed bundle on OS X 10.11.4 with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_77 and on Ubuntu 14.04 also with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_77.  If you'd like to see the full script (including this fix) in context, you can find it [here](https://github.com/VocabHunter/VocabHunter/blob/1.0.12/package/bundle-ant.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [Ant task reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm), shows that there is mention of a version attribute on `fx:application`.

You might get away with defining the version in the Manifest, but I am unsure if this will show up in the desired manner.

Comment: Thanks.  Your suggestion about the manifest is an interesting one.  I tried adding `Implementation-Version` and `Specification-Version` to the generated Jar and reran the build on Linux but I still see the same problem.  As for the `version` attribute in `fx:application`, if you look closely at the XML in the question, it is already specified.  So no luck I’m afraid.